# Compile language pack

Tags: magento-1, language-package

[image]I translated the magento. I want to create a language pack and upload to Magento. I do not know how to create packages. I tried to create a pack with "Create Extension Packag" in admin panel.  I completed the all fields.

New Extension->Contents Iset Path: `/magento/magento/app/locale/my_file/` Type: Res.Dir.

In "conncect" folder I see only tgz file with xml inside without language pack.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I translated the magento. I want to create a language pack and upload to Magento.

Comment: Ok. I've reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Mark Shust has [one of the best articles for making sense of our cumbersome extension creation process](http://markshust.com/2012/02/27/packaging-community-extension-distribution-magento-connect). It's a simpler breakdown than what we provide in our own documentation.

Please ensure that you are providing a valid locale  code (xx_XX) for the system. If you are specifying a non-existent locale we may need to update core files on our end.